# Are B, P frames results of the motion estimation/compression?

Tags: mpeg

Confused about the relationship between MPEG frames and motion estimation/compensation :(

Are B, P frames results of the motion estimation/compression? But motion estimation/ compression use those frames. Then how and who decide the frames?

Answer (score 2):

There are actually 3 types of frames:

- **I-frame** Intra-coded (independent) frame, the least compressed
- **P-frame** Predicted frame: uses precedent frames to improve compression
- **B-frame** Bi-directional frame: uses both previous and next frames for the best compression

These frames are indeed the result of compression by the encoder, which is done in different steps, roughly (not exhaustive):

- Reduce color nuances & resolution of images
- Remove imperceptible details
- *Compare adjacent images and remove redundant informations (i.e. unchanged items between 2 images)*
- [...]

There is a good article on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_compression_picture_types). You can find [more](http://www.streaminglearningcenter.com/articles/producing-h264-video-for-flash-an-overview.html?page=4) asking google on I/P/B frames ;)

Also checkout this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23440956/3194340) related to your question.